# How does one horizontally distribute a website

Tags: http, networking, web, distributed

How can one horizontally spread the hits to a certain web app across multiple servers?  It seems that domain names can only route to one IP address and as a result one server.

So is the only way to achieve horizontal distribution is by making that server a proxy?  If not what are the different ways to horizontally distribute your app?

Comment: " It seems that domain names can only route to one IP address and as a result one server." check up on DNS round robin

Comment: There are also hardware appliances which do this. They keep tack of the flows for each of the redundant servers.

Comment: You need to read up on Load distribution, Load balancing

Comment: Yes indeed, load balancer is the right answer most likely.